# Trouble hooking Polyglot Notebook up to MySQL in C# with a magic connection

Tags: mysql, polyglot, dotnet-interactive

I am migrating some existing Python Jupyter Notebooks to C# Polyglot Notebooks. A MySQL connection is a mission-critical component of the notebooks, and I am new to Polyglot Notebooks. I've been able to successfully get Polyglot running in VSC and connect Polyglot to SQLServer with a magic-based connection. Anyone know how to do the same with MySQL?

I've been searching for instructions on how to do this to no avail. Is it possible to do right now? If so, how?